# Optimizing spark-sql join with salted_key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data `channel` dataset, i am trying to find the similarity score using it essentially intersection over union of `users_id` across `time of day`, `channel_id` and `day of week`
my data format:

```
+--------------------+---+---+----------+
|             user_id|dow|tod|channel_id|
+--------------------+---+---+----------+
|               user1|  1| 10|       111|
|               user2|  6| 21|       111|
|               user1|  1| 19|       123|
|               user1|  1| 20|       124|
|               user3|  1| 21|       009|
|               user4|  1| 10|       900|
+--------------------+---+---+----------+
```

as data is heavily skewed on `channel_id` `111` i am using salting technique to run this faster, and below is my code:

```
val channel_view_by_time = sqlContext.sql("select distinct user_id, dow, tod, channel_id from user_agg_master_table where channel_id not in (111) ")
channel_view_by_time.createOrReplaceTempView("channel_view_by_time")

val uniondf = sqlContext.sql("select " +
  "distinct u1.user_id, u1.channel_id, u1.dow, u1.tod as tod1,  u2.tod as tod2 " +
  "from channel_view_by_time u1 " +
  "inner join channel_view_by_time u2 on u1.channel_id=u2.channel_id and u1.dow=u2.dow ")

val uniondf_t1t2 = uniondf
  .withColumn("t2" ,when('tod2 < 'tod1 ,  'tod1 ).otherwise('tod2).cast("int"))
  .withColumn("t1" ,when('tod2 < 'tod1 ,  'tod2 ).otherwise('tod1).cast("int"))
  .drop("tod2","tod1")

uniondf_t1t2.createOrReplaceTempView("uniondf_t1t2")

val similaritytable = sqlContext.sql("select  channel_id, dow, t1,t2,  " +
  "CASE " +
  "WHEN t1 == t2 THEN 1 " +
  "ELSE (count(user_id)-count(distinct user_id))/count(distinct user_id) " +
  "END as similarityscore " +
  "from uniondf_t1t2 group by channel_id, dow, t1,t2  ")
```

for `channel_id` `111` alone i am using salting technique:

```
val channel_view_by_time_popular = sqlContext.sql("select distinct user_id, dow, tod, channel_id from user_agg_master_table where channel_id in (111) ")
channel_view_by_time_popular.createOrReplaceTempView("channel_view_by_time_popular")
val explode_factor = conf.getInt("explode_factor")

//Using salting technique to optimize run time.
val df_salted = spark.sql("select concat(channel_id,'_', Floor(RAND(1234)*"+explode_factor+")) as salted_key, * from channel_view_by_time_popular ")
df_salted.createOrReplaceTempView("df_salted")

val mySeq = List.range(0, explode_factor.toInt, 1).map(x=>lit(x))
val exploded_df = channel_view_by_time_popular.withColumn("salted_key", explode(array(mySeq:_*)))
exploded_df.createOrReplaceTempView("exploded_df")

val optimized_df = sqlContext.sql("select " +
  "distinct u1.user_id, u1.channel_id, u1.dow, u1.tod as tod1,  u2.tod as tod2 " +
  "from df_salted u1 " +
  "inner join exploded_df u2 on u1.salted_key=concat(u2.channel_id, '_',u2.salted_key) and u1.dow=u2.dow ")

val uniondf_t1t2_popular = optimized_df
  .withColumn("t2" ,when('tod2 < 'tod1 ,  'tod1 ).otherwise('tod2).cast("int"))
  .withColumn("t1" ,when('tod2 < 'tod1 ,  'tod2 ).otherwise('tod1).cast("int"))
  .drop("tod2","tod1")

uniondf_t1t2_popular.createOrReplaceTempView("uniondf_t1t2_popular")

val similaritytable_popular = sqlContext.sql("select  channel_id, dow, t1,t2,  " +
  "CASE " +
  "WHEN t1 == t2 THEN 1 " +
  "ELSE (count(user_id)-count(distinct user_id))/count(distinct user_id) " +
  "END as similarityscore " +
  "from uniondf_t1t2_popular group by channel_id, dow, t1,t2  ")
```

finally, I take a union of both the result sets.

first part runs fine as data is uniformly distributed.
coming to the second part it completes 90% of tasks pretty quick but will be stuck in the last few tasks this is because there is abnormal distribution of data across tasks:

below is the distribution across tasks when `explode_factor` is `1`:
[image]

below is the distribution across tasks when `explode_factor` is `10`:
[image]

i could see the skewness of data distribution across tasks is decreased but, i cant increase `explode_factor` more than `10` as i am doing inner join and data will be increased in size resulting in further slowness.

i Also tried the join part with broadcast but no luck, it is even taking more time than salting technique:

```
val unionbroadcastdf =  channel_view_by_time.alias("t1")
  .join(broadcast(channel_view_by_time.alias("t2")),
    $"t1.channel_id" === $"t2.channel_id" and $"t1.dow" === $"t2.dow"
  ).select($"t1.user_id", $"t1.channel_id", $"t1.dow", $"t1.tod".alias("tod1"),  $"t2.tod".alias("tod2")).distinct()
```

Any other ways to improve performance. or any other logic to achive the same result. Please help.

Comment: Could you explain you issue with the help of example,what is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is `similaritytable_popular` above code works fine, I want to optimize it for run time. creating `optimized_df` task will have 200 tasks and it will get stuck at the last task for 10 min and all previous 199 tasks will finish up in 10seconds. same case even after using the salting technique with a little improvement in performance. Data size is around 800M records.

Comment: I think you can use windowing operation instead of self join, that will be more optimised than your approach.

Comment: @Nikk I think my data suits to do windowing on column `tod` but im still yet to get there, if you have an idea can you please provide more information.